# Google apps script: Search all documents in a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

You can search for a string in all documents in a folder with GAS and return the list of found documents? give me a hint of how to do?

thank

raffaele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#searchFiles%28String%29) , read also the details about search arguments [described here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters).

They give an example too, below it an example with your requirements :

```
    function testSearch(){
    // Log the name of every file that contains a certain string
    // you can get the folder of your choice here by its ID or by its name, in the second case the returned object is a folder iterator so you will have to iterate its content. There are examples all around on how to do that.
      var files = DriveApp.getRootFolder().searchFiles( 
      'fullText contains "example"');
        while (files.hasNext()) {
          var file = files.next();
          Logger.log(file.getName());
      }
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply and timeliness. I'm not a programmer but I'm really into google apps script. study and then try to create a web application. thanks again.

Comment: Serge I understand the operation but I can not view files of subfolders. you have an idea? CODE: // work fine ONE LIVEL FOLDER
var search = '"dfdgfffdgffdzYy1mZjUyYjQ5MGY3MzE" in parents'; // Folder with files 
//NOT work
var search = '"dfffggfdgTkhhQ4543saddsd5MGY3MzE" in parents'; // Folder with subfolder with files

 var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(search);
   while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   Logger.log(file.getName());
 }
 }