# Search in DriveApp doesn't find many files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm working with the DriveApp in Google Apps Script and try to find documents, that contain a certain word or phrase:

```js
function SearchFile(Phrase, FolderID) {
  var SearchString = 'fullText contains "' + Phrase + '" and "' + FolderID + '" in parents';
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(SearchString);

  return Output(files);
}
```

That works quite well so far, but it does only find a few files. I don't understand why. I have about 30 documents in that Folder that all contain the word "Hello". But search only find's 8 of them. Same with other words.

It seems like there is a bug in search?

Comment: likely you arent paging results.

Comment: Related:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661979/searching-for-file-by-name-within-a-folder-in-google-drive-using-google-scripts. See documentation for [DriveApp.searchFiles(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams)

Answer (score 1):

Not enough information, but as you only menion that many files "contain" the word Hello, I will assume that the word Hello is anywhere in the name in your case.

First thing that comes to mind are the following 2 from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters)

This one is when using the `name` field

> The **contains** operator only performs prefix matching for a **name**. For
>   example, the name "HelloWorld" would match for **name contains 'Hello'**
>   but not **name contains 'World'**.

This one applies when using `fullText` fields

> The **contains** operator only performs matching on entire string tokens
>   for **fullText**. For example, if the full text of a doc contains the
>   string "HelloWorld" only the query **fullText contains 'HelloWorld'**
>   returns a result. Queries such as **fullText contains 'Hello'** do not
>   return results in this scenario.