# Google App Script read the file in a specific folder

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I read file data with its name in specific directory? The code I'm writing doesn't work: I don't know what conditions it needs to run.

```
 function readFile() {
        var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('1YQKc_hJF6KuTjcAf77GunubNKKmm0Bfo').getFilesByName("the_file.txt");
        if (files.hasNext()) {
          var file = files.next();
          var Id = file.getId();
          Logger.log(Id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Searching for file by name within a folder in google Drive using google scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661979/searching-for-file-by-name-within-a-folder-in-google-drive-using-google-scripts)

Comment: Thank you for the help.
My question is wrong because I entered site drive id
Your suggestion is correct but I need to browse the directory and find the file I need. It will take longer than my current method

Comment: It is working for me. I am getting the file Id, that is what you wanted right?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this function will be of some assistance:
It provides a dialog that gives you the filename, file id and file type for all the files in a folder. It has a prompt where you have to enter the folder id.

I use this myself.  I keep it in a library.

```
function getFoldersFileInfo() {
  var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Folder Id","Enter Folder Id", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(resp.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK && resp.getResponseText().length>0) {
    try{
      var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(resp.getResponseText());
      var files=folder.getFiles();
      var html='<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;padding:2px 5px;}</style><table><tr><th>File Name</th><th>File Id</th><th>Type</th></tr>';
      while(files.hasNext()) {
        var file=files.next();
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>', file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getMimeType());
      }
      html+='</table><br /><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
      var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(800).setHeight(400);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Files in Folder: " + folder.getName());
    }
    catch(e){SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(e);}
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Invalid or Missing Inputs: No FileId Provided");
  }
}
```