# Attempting to ID a converted google form file, then move that file to the assign folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Here's the broad scope of my setup; User fills out a google form for a new lead. From that linked spread sheet, specific information is recorded into a google doc that is saved to a folder in google drive. That destination folder is essentially a 'hand-off' point for a convert-google-doc-to-pdf script. The google doc is deleted and the pdf is then deposited in a new folder that has different users folders within it.

With that in mind here is my predicament. The file is saved in the format of 'user custname typeofwork'. I've been attempting to modify a script that identifies the file by the users name, and then moves it to their respective folder within the same location. It "runs" with no noted errors but the files do not move.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function moveFiles(files, destination){
  var searchFor = ('title contains "Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3", "Name 4", "Name 5"'); //Searching for file with specific keyword
  var names =[];
  var fileIds =[];
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('ThisIsWherePDFsAreStored').getFilesByName(searchFor); //Searching for those files within 'original folder'
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileId = file.getId();// Getting FileId of the file
    fileIds.push(fileId);
    var name = file.getName(); //Getting Name of the searched file
    names.push(name);
    var copyFile = name.makeCopy(name.getName());
    var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderWhereUsersFoldersAre').getFoldersByName("Name 1", 
    "Name 2", "Name 3", "Name 4", "Name 5"); //File destination folder by actual name
    copyFile.makeCopy(destination);
    file.isTrashed(true); //Remove original file
  }
}
```

Here is the post that contains the script above: [Searching for file by name within a folder in google Drive using google scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661979/searching-for-file-by-name-within-a-folder-in-google-drive-using-google-scripts)

I then am attempting to add a 'copy & move' script but to no avail.

Perhaps there's a better way as in to deposit the google doc directly into that specific users file based on cell input and delay the convert-to-pdf script until the doc is in its destined folder? I think the answer for that requires an array...

"heres file names x, y, z in this location"
"if file has x, put in x folder"

I've taken the time to watch how-to on arrays but I cant seem to find one that calls a source file and identifies those objects within, then assigns the document from a different source into the file that matches

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: When you run the function does `files` contain the file your looking for?

Comment: try: ` while (files.hasNext()) {var file = files.next();Logger.log(file.getId())`

Comment: It does not. The message displayed is "No logs yet. Please wait". Unless I'm doing it wrong

Comment: Try viewing executions.

Comment: As an alternative you can write the data to a dialog of your own design to view the data.

Comment: Executions have all been completed, no logs. No recorded failures.

Comment: getFilesByName() requires a single string.  Perhaps you would prefer using DriveApp search Methods.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that. Your comment actually pointed me in the right direction. I will work on integrating one at first. Then I will attempt to incorporate two.. then three.. so on. I made the mistake of attempting the whole package without taking time to understand the basic fundamentals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

- There are several files in a certain folder, whose title contain `Name 1`, `Name 2`, etc. You want to retrieve these files and copy them to different folders (children of a known folder) named `Name 1`, `Name 2`, etc.
- You are mixing up [getFilesByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String)), which can be used to retrieve files with a certain name, with [searchFiles(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#searchFiles(String)), which can be used to make [more advanced search queries](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms), like "look for files than **contain** a certain string" (that is, not an exact match).

#### Solution:

- Build an appropriate `query search` string based on the array of user names (`Name 1`, `Name 2`, etc.). The files should have the `PDF folder` as parent and its title should include at least one of `Name 1`, `Name 2`, etc. There are several ways to do this, but I used [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in the example below.
- Iterate through these files, and for each file, look for the corresponding user name.
- Once the user name, find the corresponding folder (named the same way) and copy the file there.

#### Code sample:

```
function moveFiles() {
  const fileNames = ["Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3", "Name 4", "Name 5"];
  const pdfFolderId = "{source-folder-id}";
  const usersParentFolderId = "{destination-folders-parent-id}";
  let querySearch = "'" + pdfFolderId + "' in parents and (";
  querySearch = fileNames.reduce((acc, fileName, index) => {
    if (index < fileNames.length - 1) {
      return acc + "title contains '" + fileName + "' or ";
    } else {
      return acc + "title contains '" + fileName + "')"
    }
  }, querySearch);

  const pdfFiles = DriveApp.searchFiles(querySearch);
  const usersParentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(usersParentFolderId);
  while (pdfFiles.hasNext()) {
    const file = pdfFiles.next();
    const fileName = fileNames.find(fileName => file.getName().includes(fileName));
    const userFolder = usersParentFolder.getFoldersByName(fileName).next(); // This assumes there is only one folder with this name (iterate if that's not the case)
    file.makeCopy(userFolder); 
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Search query terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms)

Comment: Thank you! I've looked over the terms you used and have found that a const is a one-time-use variable, correct? Or is it that it is unmodifiable? I've figured out a method to remove the pdf from the pdfFolder as it repeats copying and moving the file. It is a function that finds the pdfFolder and deletes all files. It operates as intended, but since it is triggered by time, sometimes the triggers overlap and the newly converted pdf is deleted before the moveFile function trigger is activated. Adding the file.isTrashed(true) after the 'while' statement did not work.

Comment: @BoredRoofer You're welcome. See [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const). About your issue with a time-based trigger, I'd suggest you to post another question to tackle this.